# Nginx serving a lot of write connections?

Tags: nginx

My iostat is showing close to %util at all times so I looked at the nginx connections report and saw

```
Active connections: 2856 
server accepts handled requests
 1200179 1200179 1196926 
Reading: 6 Writing: 2850 Waiting: 0
```

My site shouldn't have that many write connections, is there a way to see what they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't mean that nginx is reading/writting from/to disk. That's not disk I/O.

There is a description of stub_status module output:
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule#stub_status